# Some help for rewriting this complex function

Tags: complex

I have here a complex function in which z =x+ I y must be filled in

`f[z_] := E^(-z^2)`

By hand : `(-E^(-x^2))*E^y^2*(Cos[2*x*y]-I*Sin[2*x*y])`
Can this be derived in MMA ?

I tried to use z= x+Iy and the formula of Euler, but don't get
the manual outcome?

By hand inference the answer should come out listed here.
Unfortunately, I am not yet getting to this manual derivation.

I wonder if this is really so important now because there are further calculations to be made.

But yes I am trying to follow a math text.

Comment: `Simplify@ComplexExpand@f[x + I y]`?

Comment: @kglr, how easy can it be :)
ComplexExpand command was not present by me

Comment: @janhardo please have a look at the edit. I am hoping that now is  clear that there's a loose sign in your expression.

Comment: You haven't accept many, if any, answers. It's polite to thank people by doing so. Please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @Michael E2,  Please clarify exactly what you mean by accepting answers.
Do you mean my response to the help in the comments. ?
The checkmark sign is familiar to me, so I use that for everyone. 

Yes, thanking people for their effort is the least i can do
But be assured that I appreciate everyone who helps me.

In the future I will thank everyone always and no longer as now, yes and then not.
It's sensitive it turns out, so don't want to deprive anyone of the appreciation I have for someone helping me out with the math.

Comment: Click on the link in my last comment for an explanation. -- You can tell by looking at the (top) answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265877/why-does-the-function-replacement-not-work-here): It has a green checkmark, marking it as the answer the OP thought best solved their problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I just want to point out that accepting answers is more important for other users who might face the same difficulties. It's much easier for one to have a look at an answer that one knows that solves successfully a question and then if they so desire have a look at alternatives. Just as a very general thought.

Comment: @bmf have you read the linked meta q&a? It has an extensive discussion of the benefits of accepting answers.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have, yes, and I did not mean to imply that you were not aware or you did not provide enough info. I just made a brief comment mentioning what the most important aspect for me is. That's all. :-) Now that I saw my comment, I realize that I did not write it properly and does not make much sense. Sorry

Comment: @bmf no problem. For that matter, I like to comment in terms of politeness because it tends to get the attention of new users that they are participants in a community that has norms. I think it helps the community if answerers feel appreciated, whatever other benefits there are too accepting answers. And I think become better community members as they figure out how to participate in better ways.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I totally agree with you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works if I am not mistaken

```
E^(-z^2) /. z -> x + I y // ComplexExpand // Factor
```

> E^(-x^2 + y^2) (Cos[2 x y] - I Sin[2 x y])

Edit: I believe there's a small typo in the OP. An overall sign, i.e this

Just to make it clearer

In the OP this is written

```
janhardo = (-E^(-x^2))*E^y^2*(Cos[2*x*y] - I*Sin[2*x*y]);
```

Mathematica gives us this

```
mma = E^(-z^2) /. z -> x + I y // ComplexExpand // Factor;
```

If I subtract I should get zero, but I don't.

```
janhardo - mma // FullSimplify
```

> `-2 E^-(x + I y)^2`

If I add them

```
janhardo + mma
```

> `0`

hence an overall minus sign missing.

Better understanding, just divide

```
janhardo/mma // FullSimplify
```

> `-1`.

Edit: final comment. This is not really related to Mathematica, but Maths.

The expression after substitution is

```
Exp[-x^2 + y^2]
```

which can be written as `Exp[-x^2] Exp[y^2]`. Verification:

```
Exp[-x^2 + y^2]/(Exp[-x^2] Exp[y^2]) // FullSimplify
```

> `1`

But in the OP it is written as `-Exp[-x^2]*Exp[y^2]`.

```
Exp[-x^2 + y^2]/(-Exp[-x^2]*Exp[y^2]) // FullSimplify
```

> `-1`

Comment: thanks, it was ComplexExpand needed.
Unfortunately it was not yet ready with me 
I'm so used to Expand...i forget ComplexExpand
I checked my typed in manually obtained formula, but don't see the typo?

Comment: @janhardo it's easy enough to understand why I suggested it. You gave a formula. I copied, pasted and subtracted from the expression after `ComplexExpand//Factor`. It should give zero, but it does not. When I sum them, you get a zero, hence there must be an overall minus sign. You can check for yourself

Comment: thanks . Indeed a typo then : a minus sign  before the e power manual formula.
MMA gives the right answer now: now doubt abou tthis .

Comment: @janhardo glad I was able to help. If you found this answer useful, you can consider [`accepting it`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the checkmark sign :-)

Comment: bmf, i did now choose for your excellent answer for rating: useful and as best answer too (although there is one answer, its a best one )

Comment: @janhardo many thanks. I really appreciate it :-)