# Why does the function replacement not work here?

Tags: replacement

why does the function replacement not work here?

```
b[1, x_] := x^2;
a'[x] /. a -> Function[x, b[1, x]]
```

gives  $b^{(0,1)}(1,x)$ without evaluating further.

I would like the output to be $2x$

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica can't (won't) calculate the partial derivative of the function `b`, if it does not know what it does for general values of all inputs.

If the other input is not meant to be a variable (but say a parameter in the function), the following definition works:

```
b[1][x_] := x^2;
a'[x] /. a -> Function[x, b[1][x]]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
b[1, x_] := x^2;

a'[x] /. a -> Function[x, Evaluate @ b[1, x]]
```

> ```
> 2 x
> ```

#### *"why does the function replacement not work here?"*

```
Attributes[Function]
```

> ```
> {HoldAll, Protected}
> ```

That is, *"all arguments to* `Function` *are to be maintained in an unevaluated form"*.

Wrapping `body` in `Function[arg, body]` with `Evaluate` causes `body` *"to be evaluated even if it appears as the argument of a function whose attributes specify that it should be held unevaluated."*

Use `Trace` to see why we get $b^{(0,1)}(1,x)$ when we don't force evaluation of `b[1, x]`:

```
a'[x] /. a -> Function[x, b[1, x]] // Trace // Column
```

[image]